# Rails Test "ActionController::UnknownFormat: is missing a template for this request format and variant"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, integration-testing

I'm creating a testing suite for a Twitter clone app called "Canary" and I'm having a hard time writing integration tests for chirps#reply and chirps#rechirps

Chirps Controller

```
def reply
    @chirp = current_user.chirps.new
    @parent = Chirp.find_by(id: params[:parent_id])
    @chirp.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
    end
end

def rechirp
    @chirp = current_user.chirps.new
    @reference = Chirp.find_by(id: params[:reference_id])
    @chirp.reference_id = params[:reference_id]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
    end 
end
```

Chirp View

```
<%= link_to reply_chirp_path(current_user, parent_id: chirp.id), remote: true, data: { target: '#modal_container', toggle: 'modal' } do %>
    <%= icon('far', 'comment') %> <%= chirp.children.size if chirp.children.size > 0 %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to rechirp_chirp_path(current_user, reference_id: chirp.id), remote: true, data: { target: '#modal_container', toggle: 'modal' } do %>
    <%= icon('fas', 'retweet') %> <%= count_rechirps(chirp) %>
<% end %>
```

Reply.js.erb

```
$("#modal_container").find(".modal-content").html("<%= j render 'chirps/modal_reply' %>");
$("#modal_container").modal('show', 'focus');
```

Rechirp.js.erb

```
$("#modal_container").find(".modal-content").html("<%= j render 'chirps/modal_rechirp' %>");
$("#modal_container").modal('show', 'focus');
```

Chirps Interface Test

```
# Try to reply to chirp
assert_select 'a[href=?]', reply_chirp_path(@user, parent_id: @chirp.id)
assert_difference 'Chirp.count', 1 do
    get reply_chirp_path(@user, parent_id: @chirp)
    assert_select 'div#modal_container > div.modal-dialog > div.modal-content > div.modal-body'
    post chirps_path, params: { chirp: { content: content, parent_id: @chirp.id } }
    assert :success
end
assert_redirected_to root_url
follow_redirect!
# Try to rechirp chirp
assert_select 'a[href=?]', rechirp_chirp_path(@user, reference_id: @chirp.id)
```

When I run chirp_interface_test.rb I keep encountering the same error:

> Error:
>   ChirpsInterfaceTest#test_chirp_interface:
>
> ActionController::UnknownFormat: ChirpsController#reply is missing a template for this request format and variant.
>
> request.formats: ["text/html"]
>
> request.variant: []
>
> ```
> test/integration/chirps_interface_test.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ChirpsInterfaceTest>'
>
> test/integration/chirps_interface_test.rb:29:in `block in <class:ChirpsInterfaceTest>'
> ```

I know that the routes work in app because I've successfully submitted by replies and rechirps multiple times through the localhost. How can I test that these actions work properly with rails testing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Error: ChirpsInterfaceTest#test_chirp_interface:
>
> ActionController::UnknownFormat: ChirpsController#reply is missing a
>   template for this request format and variant.
>
> request.formats: ["text/html"]
>
> request.variant: []

Your links have `remote: true`. That means the request is `JS`. To test such links, you should use `xhr: true` like so

```
get reply_chirp_path(@user, parent_id: @chirp), xhr: true
```

Since you haven't specified this, the request is treated as `HTML` and fails with that exception.

For more info, read [*Testing XHR (AJAX) requests*](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-xhr-ajax-requests)